# View the application on specific branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I'm learning ruby on rails right now, and it seems i can't get something really basic.
From my understanding, the reason to use git and different branches is to avoid working on the "master" application, which will allow me to keep developing and upgrading the application without disturbing the working application.

When i use `git checkout -b version-under-development` i switch to "version under development" branch, but how can i see the output of this specific branch on the server without switching it to be the master branch?

Is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be running a local copy of your app for   development purposes. Use `rails server` to start it. All your   development work should be done on this local instance, on whichever branch you check out, before you worry about viewing your changes on your remote server.

Comment: So, there is no option to run the server on a specific branch and not the master?

Comment: No, you don't need such an option, just check out the branch. That's all. The server will use whichever files are in the working directory, as provided by the current branch.